# How to handle Missing Controler in yii

Tags: php, yii

As we have seen in controller that there is one function missingAction($actionID) in CController. By using this function I can simply tell my application that what it should do when one action is missing in a controller.

```
public function missingAction($actionId) {
    throw new CHttpException(404, Yii::t('yii', 'The system is unable to find the requested action "{action}".', array('{action}' => $actionId == '' ? $this->defaultAction : $actionId)));      
}
```

Is there any such function by over ridding which I can simply implement the same thing for controller. i.e missingController kinda thing.

Also is there any such function or any configuration available for Module, so that if one module is not found it can be handled?

Comment: In Yii2 there is configuration option: components -> errorHandler -> errorAction: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html. It will redirect all not found errors to that action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any function that you can override for this, but you could use `onBeginRequest` behavior in your config's `main.php` file to check if a controller exists or not. Here is an example:

Create a file in `protected/components` folder called `ControllerCheck.php`. Now the contents of `ControllerCheck.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * ControllerCheck Component to check if controller exists
 */
class ControllerCheck extends CBehavior
{
    public function attach($owner)
    {
        $owner->attachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this, 'handleBeginRequest'));
    }

    public function handleBeginRequest($event)
    {
        $path = explode("/", Yii::app()->request->pathInfo);
        if($path[0] != "site") {// you could add as many controllers name as you want or you could use php in_array function
            $redirectUrl = Yii::app()->createUrl('myController/myAction');
            Yii::app()->request->redirect($redirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this behavior has to be called whenever the application processes a request, to do that open your `main.php` file in `protected/config` and add the following:

```
return array(
...
'behaviors' => array(
            'onBeginRequest' => array(
                    'class' => 'application.components.ControllerCheck'
            )
    ),
);
```

Thats it. So, in this case if a controller other than `site` is requested then it will redirect to `myController/myAction`.

Hope that gives an idea.